# How to pass non-texture data to SCNTechnique Metal shaders

Tags: shader, scenekit, metal, scntranscaction

I can a pass custom parameter of type `sampler2D` to the `Metal fragment function` of an `SCNTechnique` and I have a working 2nd pass:

PList:

```
<key>inputs</key>
<dict>
    <key>imageFromPass1</key>
    <string>COLOR</string>
    <key>myCustomImage</key>
    <string>myCustomImage_sym</string>
</dict>
```

...

```
<key>symbols</key>
<dict>
    <key>myCustomImage_sym</key>
    <dict>
        <key>type</key>
        <string>sampler2D</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Relevant Obj-C code:

```
[technique setValue: UIImagePNGRepresentation(myCustomTexture) forKey:@"myCustomImage_sym"];
```

Metal function parameters:

```
fragment half4 myFS(out_vertex_t vert [[stage_in]],
    texture2d<float, access::sample> imageFromPass1 [[texture(0)]],
    texture2d<float, access::sample> myCustomImage [[texture(1)]],
    constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]]) { ...
```

I access and use all these inputs in the shader function. It Works!

## So far so good!

However, when I add another custom parameter of type `float` ...

```
<key>blob_pos</key>
<string>blob_pos_sym</string>
```

...

```
<key>blob_pos_sym</key>
<dict>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>float</string>
</dict>
```

---

```
[_sceneView.technique setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f] forKey:@"blob_pos_sym"];
```

---

```
 constant float& blob_pos [[buffer(2)]]
```

... the passed values never reach the shader function.

## I have tried

- using different buffer(N) values up to 6
- having the custom parameter in the vertex function
- type vec3 and float3 instead of type float
- different means of encoding my float to NSData
- wrapping my float in a struct

  ```
  [technique setValue:[NSValue valueWithSCNVector3: SCNVector3Make(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)] forKey:@"blob_pos_"];

  SCNVector3 xx = SCNVector3Make(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  [technique setValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:&xx length:sizeof(xx)] forKey:@"blob_pos_"];
  [technique setValue:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:&xx length:sizeof(xx)] forKey:@"blob_pos_"];

  simd_float3 x = simd_make_float3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  [technique setValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:&x length:sizeof(x)] forKey:@"blob_pos_"];

  float y = 0.5;
  [technique setValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:&y length:sizeof(y)] forKey:@"blob_pos_"];

  struct MyStruct {
      float x;
  };
  struct MyStruct myStruct = {
      0.5
  };

  [technique setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&myStruct objCType:@encode(struct MyStruct)] forKey:@"blob_pos_"];
  [technique setObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&myStruct objCType:@encode(struct MyStruct)] forKeyedSubscript:@"blob_pos_"];
  ```

... and it all failed.

Then I looked at [handleBindingOfSymbol:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique/1520490-handlebindingofsymbol) ... but it is GLSL only.

I found it's Metal counterpart, [handleBindingOfBufferNamed:frequency:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnprogram/1524047-handlebindingofbuffernamed) ... which is not available in SCNTechnique.

I Googled [SCNTechnique Metal](https://www.google.com/search?q=scntechnique%20metal) ... and realized *all* of the projects used sampler2D parameters only.

Finally I learned that this isn't new but [bugs developers for years](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26726).

Before I go and encode this float in a texture, let me know the missing bit to make it work the way intended.

Comment: FYI this is the workaround I found usable pending a proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026751/low-cost-image-to-nsdata-conversion-for-feeding-scntechniques-sampler2d-inputs/51044303#51044303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a struct to wrap your input symbols and be sure to use `[SCNTechnique setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]` to pass in your symbol values to your technique. The documentation for [setObject:forKeyedSubscript:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique/1520495-setobject?language=objc) mentions Metal however it doesn't explain how to receive the value in a Metal function, which is unfortunate.

Using your example:

Technique Definition:

```
"inputs": [
    "imageFromPass1": "COLOR",
    "myCustomImage": "myCustomImage_sym",
    "blob_pos": "blob_pos_sym",
],
...

"symbols": [
    "myCustomImage_sym": ["type": "sampler2D"],
    "blob_pos_sym": ["type": "float"]
 ]
```

Obj-C:

```
[_sceneView.technique setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f] forKeyedSubscript:@"blob_pos_sym"];
```

Metal:

```
typedef struct {
    float blob_pos; // Must be spelled exactly the same as in inputs dictionary.
} Inputs;

fragment half4 myFS(out_vertex_t vert [[stage_in]],
    texture2d<float, access::sample> imageFromPass1 [[texture(0)]],
    texture2d<float, access::sample> myCustomImage [[texture(1)]],
    constant Inputs& myInputs [[buffer(0)]]) { 

    float blob_pos = myInputs.blob_pos;

    ...
```

Comment: Yes, this works, and is a lot more faster than the workaround I found. I'm so glad you found it out. Thank you! How did you discover it?

Comment: I can't get this to work - been trying everything. Is there any source code that you can share?